# How to get the remote ip address in Tower.js?

Tags: node.js, towerjs

I'm creating web service, using Tower.js.
i was able to get the HTTP header and User-agent,but couldn't get a remote ip address.
how to get the remote ip address of requester?

I tried

1. looked for Tower.Controller class member variable and method (this.request and this.request.app and this.request.headers etc...)
2. check HTTP headers
3. read the tower-docs (https://github.com/viatropos/tower-docs)
4. read the superagent documents (https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)

If there is lack of information, add.
thanks.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: Thanks for your message.
added info.

Comment: There is no formal api for this yet, your best bet is checking the request headers on the `controller.request` object. https://github.com/viatropos/tower/issues/298

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply!

I'm checked request object.
but can't get IP address.

installed Tower 0.4.2-3 and Express 3.0.0rc5
but happen runtime error.
Is supported Express3.0 to Tower.js? Or Express 2.x can get remote ip address?

Could you please tell me.

Error message:
/var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:432
        throw err;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at Tower.Application.Application.reopen.use (/var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-application/server/application.js:115:52)
    at null. (/var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/app/config/server/bootstrap.coffee:9:12)
    at Tower.Application.Application.reopen.stack (/var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-application/server/application.js:177:16)
    at Tower.Application.Application.reopen.initialize.initializer (/var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-application/server/application.js:90:19)
    at Tower.Application.Application.reopen.configureStores (/var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-application/server/application.js:164:27)
    at _.extend.parallel (/var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-support/shared/shared.js:344:20)
    at /var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-store/server/mongodb/database.js:52:24
    at applyIndexes (/var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-store/server/mongodb/database.js:26:20)
    at /var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-store/server/mongodb/database.js:50:20
    at Db.open (/var/www/html/melissa/server2/node_modules/tower/bin/test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:258:14)

Comment: Just to update this topic... This has been implemented as of the current version of Tower. http://github.com/viatropos/tower/issues/298 you can use `@get('ip')` inside a controller.

Comment: was late reply;;
Thanks! was able to getting ip.